# Create new power plan

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have found all sorts of references to using PowerShell to change the active power plan, and I have found instructions for manually creating a new power plan, but I can't seem to find anything about using Powershell to automate the creation of a new plan. Is this something that can be done, and I need to keep looking? Or am I not finding it because it can't be done?

And, a little context, I am automating the setup of lab machines for a three day conference. The machines come from various vendors, and I have no idea nor control over what settings their Windows image is going to provide. Usually laptops are set to power down the screen at 10-15 minutes, which is crazy for a lab, where you will often go more than that listening to instruction, then when you go to try something you need a password. My goal is to have a script create a new power plan with the settings I want, and then a second script that makes that plan current for the user. I also need to make this work in PSv2 as 99% of the time we get Windows 7, and I am not in a position to demand a PS update. Eventually we will automate the OS install too, and eliminate a few more variables, but for now we are working with the OS image we get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you need to wrap `powercfg` calls in your script to produce a power plan modification. One good thing that you can call `powercfg -import <file> <GUID>`, and you can prepare the file by setting correct parameters on a test PC and call `powercfg -export` with a given plan. So you just create a `.bat` file with a power plan export result, and call that at startup to set the power plan. You can also modify current power plan by calling `powercfg -x`. See `powercfg -?` for details.

Comment: Interesting. Looks like it's old enough that spaces aren't good in the file path, and so far quotes aren't helping, but I have the infrastructure in place to copy the file locally as part of the machine setup script, then import and set active. So, looks like I am off to the races. Thanks!

Comment: Spaces should not be an issue unless you've made mistakes in forming command line for powercfg in powershell. Still, using the path that does not contain spaces always helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well I had to look into a few different places to solve exactly this problem and I came up with this following little script that does exactly this but using a batch file instead

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "src_profile=High performance"
SET "new_profile=DAW Optimised"

:CREATE_PLAN
REM Create new power plan based on the existing one specified, rename it and specify settings
echo Setting up new power plan
for /f "tokens=4" %%f in ('powercfg /list ^| findstr /C:"%src_profile%"') do set GUID=%%f
for /f "tokens=4" %%I in ('powercfg -duplicatescheme %GUID%') do set dest_GUID=%%I
powercfg /changename %dest_GUID% "%new_profile%"
powercfg /setactive %dest_GUID%
```

I'm sure that conference is long over but hopefully this helps someone in a similar situation